How to mock an oauth2 client that is instantiated outside the function?
I have a file I am trying to test - apiCallout.js. this is the rough structure.

const { google } = require('googleapis');


const GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
const GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;
const instanceURL = process.env.APP_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:5000';


const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_ID,
  GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  instanceURL + '/googleRedirect'
);

function generateOAuthLink(){
  const authorizationUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
    access_type: 'offline',
    /** Pass in the scopes array defined above.
     * Alternatively, if only one scope is needed, you can pass a scope URL as a string */
    scope: scopes,
    // Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
    include_granted_scopes: true
  });
  return authorizationUrl;
}


and this is my test file. apiCallout.test.ts
import { beforeEach, describe, expect, jest, test } from '@jest/globals';

import {
  generateOAuthLink,
} from './apiCallout';

// Mock googleapis module
jest.mock('googleapis', () => ({
  google: {
    auth: {
      OAuth2: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        setCredentials: jest.fn(),
        generateAuthUrl: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('https://mock-auth-url.com')
      }))
    },
  }
}));

describe('google.js API Functions', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  describe('testing generateOAuthLink()', () => {
    
    test('should return a valid OAuth link with correct parameters', () => {

      const link = generateOAuthLink();
      expect(link).toBe('https://mock-auth-url.com');
    });
  });
})

since my oauth2client is instantiated outside of the function, whenever i run the function in the test, it actually makes a callout to the google api as opposed to using the mock response. is there a way to override the instantiation?

I think you can move oauth2Client inside the function:
function generateOAuthLink(){
  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_ID,
    GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_SECRET,
    instanceURL + '/googleRedirect'
  );

  const authorizationUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: scopes,
    include_granted_scopes: true
  });
  return authorizationUrl;
}


just checked responses, we cannot do that, as our api functions are all built in the pattern in my example

You can use jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)
e.g.
apiCallout.js:
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_ID = process.env.BOOKIT_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
const GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.BOOKIT_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;
const instanceURL = process.env.APP_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:5000';

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_SECRET, instanceURL + '/googleRedirect');

function generateOAuthLink() {
  const authorizationUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: [],
    include_granted_scopes: true,
  });
  return authorizationUrl;
}

exports.generateOAuthLink = generateOAuthLink;

apiCallout.test.js:
describe('google.js API Functions', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  describe('testing generateOAuthLink()', () => {
    test('should return a valid OAuth link with correct parameters', () => {
      const mockOauth2Instance = {
        setCredentials: jest.fn(),
        generateAuthUrl: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('https://mock-auth-url.com'),
      };
      jest.doMock('googleapis', () => ({
        google: {
          auth: {
            OAuth2: jest.fn(() => mockOauth2Instance),
          },
        },
      }));

      const { generateOAuthLink } = require('./apiCallout');
      const link = generateOAuthLink();
      expect(link).toBe('https://mock-auth-url.com');
    });
  });
});

Test result:
 PASS  stackoverflow/78983932/apiCallout.test.js                                                                                                                                  
  google.js API Functions
    testing generateOAuthLink()                                                                                                                                                   
      √ should return a valid OAuth link with correct parameters (745 ms)                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                  
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------                                                                                                      
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s                                                                                                       
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
 apiCallout.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.159 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.


heyo! thanks for the response, ill try it out next week and report back. would you mind editing your code example to process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID and process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET? thank you!
